# ASP .NET display html tags in RadioButton.Text

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am developing a quiz application in ASP.NET. I am using radio buttons to display options like this:

rbOption1.Text = reader["Option1"].ToString();

Now, for a question related to HTML, all the options have only HTML tags in database e.g:

```
tr td /td td rowspan=”2” /td /tr
```

I have removed the `<>` signs otherwise the above example won't render here as text.

When the text for such radio buttons is rendered on webpage, then no text is displayed using `RadioButton.Text` property.

How can I force the radio buttons to display the tags as stored in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
string TestString = "This is a <Test String>.";
string EncodedString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(TestString);
```

More information here: https://www.dotnetperls.com/htmlencode-htmldecode

But the bigger question is why you want to use tables in the first place. It might be a lot simpler to look at a CSS implementation.